# Compiler Expecting Closing Bracket Without Opening Bracket

Tags: c#, asp.net

In [trying to implement authentication in CKFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319708/) by following [this "howto"](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/howto.html#howto_custom_authenticator), I've written the following file, saved to my CKFinder directory:

```
<%@page codepage="65001" language="C#" lcid="6153"%>
<%
using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core;
using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication;
public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
    public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
    }
}
%>
```

However, when I try to load it, I get the a compiler error (`CS1513`) on the line containing the second `using` statement stating that a closing bracket (`}`) is expected, despite the fact that there is no opening bracket (`{`) anywhere in the file before that line.

Given that I have next to no knowledge of ASP.NET, can someone shed some light on what's happening here and how I would go about solving it?

I have, despite knowing it wouldn't work, tried adding a `}` to the end of that line to see what would happen and it throws a different compiler error - "`CS1518`: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct" - in a completely different file "App_Web_auth.aspx.*.*.0.cs" (the asterisks being random strings of characters on each reload) which, strangely, is nested a few directories down in my `%WINDIR%`. That error occurs on line 214, which is the second line in the following extract:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
protected override void FrameworkInitialize() {
    base.FrameworkInitialize();
    this.@__BuildControlTree(this);
    this.AddWrappedFileDependencies(global::ASP.auth_aspx.@__fileDependencies);
    this.Request.ValidateInput();
}
```

## UPDATE 1

If I remove the public class completely, I get yet another compiler error - "`CS1003:` Syntax error, '(' expected" - this time on the line containing the first `using` statement. Trial and error led me to figure out that the `using` statements need to be enclosed in parnetheses but, after adding the public class back in, I still get the original error about the missing `}`.

```
<%@page codepage="65001" language="C#" lcid="6153"%>
<%
using(CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core);
using(CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication);
public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
    public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
    }
}
%>
```

Removing the class again leads to another new error - "`CS0119`: 'CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core' is a 'namespace', which is not valid in the given context"

## UPDATE 2

Per [SeM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5427842/sem)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411056/4768433), I added the following to the `system.web` section of CKF's "Web.config" file:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core" />
        <add namespace="CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

And updated the contents of my file to be:

```
<%@page codepage="65001" language="C#" lcid="6153"%>
<%@import namespace="ConnectorBuilder.SetAuthenticator"%>
<%
public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
    public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
    }
}
%>
```

This, however, leads to the original error ("`CS1513`: } expected") now being thrown on line 214 (first line in below extract) of that mystery file in my `%WINDIR%` - with the added weirdness of the contents of that file having somehow changed.

```
private void @__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter @__w, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer) {

    #line 3 "x:\redacted\path\to\myfile.aspx"

public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
    public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
    }
}


    #line default
    #line hidden
}
```

## UPDATE 3

Changing my file to use a `script` tag:

```
<%@page codepage="65001" language="c#" lcid="6153"%>
<%@import namespace="ConnectorBuilder.SetAuthenticator"%>
<script language="c#" runat="server">
    public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
        public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
            return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Leads to a brand new error on line 2: "`CS0246`: The type or namespace name 'ConnectorBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

## UPDATE 4

I removed the `import` directive and received the following error on the line declaring the public task: "`CS0246`: The type or namespace name 'CancellationToken' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Comment: Your second code snippet is missing a closing `}`.

Comment: That's simply the 4 line extract provided with the error message, @ChrisF. But I opened that file to double check and the `}` is present. I'll update momentarily to include it, to avoid more confusion there, thanks.

Comment: May be you should try this: add namespaces into your web config then use `<%@ Import namespace="MyProgram.MyNamespace" %>` in your aspx page? [see this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697169/is-it-possible-to-use-the-using-statement-in-my-aspx-views-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I tried adding that line, @SeM, no change. I even tried changing `MyProgram.MyNamespace` to `ConnectorBuilder.SetAuthenticator` with the same result.

Comment: @Shaggy of course you should change the `MyProgram.MyNamespace`.

Comment: @Shaggy what if you will delete `<%@import namespace="ConnectorBuilder.SetAuthenticator"%>` line. Sorry i'm not able to test the code, so I'll try it later, if the problem will not be solved.

Comment: @SeM, removing it led to another error, detailed in update 4 above.

Comment: @Shaggy what is the namespace of `CancellationToken`?

Comment: Where would I find that information, @SeM? As I mentioned in my question, I have almost no knowledge of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### aspx

```
<%@page codepage="65001" language="C#" lcid="6153"%>
<%@ Import namespace="YourProgram.YourNamespace" %>
<%
public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
    public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
    }
}
%>
```

### web.config

```
<system.web>    
<pages>
   <namespaces>
      <add namespace="CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core" />
      <add namespace="CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication" />
   </namespaces>
</pages>
```

### Update:

please try this on you `aspx` page:

```
<%@page codepage="65001" language="C#" lcid="6153"%>
<%@ Import namespace="ConnectorBuilder.SetAuthenticator" %>
<script language="c#" runat="server">
    public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator
    {
        public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Shaggy Can you please provide details about this error? (please update it on your question to make it readable)

Comment: Thanks for your continued efforts, @SeM but still no joy - see update 3 in my question. I'm beginning to suspect that either the documentation is incomplete or it assumes a knowledge of ASP.NET that is beyond reasonable.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted for setting me on the right path of using `import` instead of `using`.

Comment: I'm glad, that I've helped you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

After a ridiculous amount of trial & error, I managed to get the problem sorted but I still don't know what the cause or the fix was or why this code works but the code provided in the documentation doesn't. One thing I did manage to figure out is that three of the `using` statements from the documentation that I'd dismissed as irrelevant to my use case were actually relevant. My file now looks like this:

```
<%@page codepage="65001" debug="true" lcid="6153"%>
<%@import namespace="System.Linq"%>
<%@import namespace="System.Threading"%>
<%@import namespace="System.Threading.Tasks"%>
<%@import namespace="CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core"%>
<%@import namespace="CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication"%>
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public class MyAuthenticator:IAuthenticator{
    public Task<IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest,CancellationToken cancellationToken){
        return Task.FromResult((IUser)new User(true,"editor"));
    }
}
</script>
```

It's still throwing an error related to the `"editor"` string being passed to the `User` function but that is unrelated to the question posed here.